# Error while installing EPEL 5.4 on virtualized Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, rpm, epel

I'm trying to install epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm in Ubuntu 14.04 (on VirtualBox).

This step is required to make a software installation.

I tried the command:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http :// download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

But the host download.fedora.redhat.com is unknown (at the moment).

This url seems to work: 
https :// dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm

I execute the command:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

But this is the error:

> warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.9Y0b8t: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, ID key 217521f6: NOKEY error: Failed dependencies: redhat-release >= 5 is needed by epel-release-5-4.noarch

I tried to find some suggestions but no one solved my problem.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: using rpms on ubuntu is non standard.  You mention virtualbox.  Are you installing in a guest in virtualbox?  Exactly what operating system does the host that you are trying to rpm install epel to have??

Comment: I found a way to install my software to Ubuntu without pass on RPM libraries. I didn.'t know that Linux is different on DEB and RPM, i was wrong because i thought that it was always a Unix system!